# Why $\Gamma \vdash A \; \mathrm{type}$ instead of $\Gamma \vdash A :\mathrm{type}$, etc?

Tags: logic, type-theory

I am learning type theory from nlab articles.

The following is from [typed predicate logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/typed+predicate+logic).

> #### Judgments and contexts
>
> Typed predicate logic is a type theory which consists of two layers, a
> layer for types and a layer for propositions.
>
> We have the basic judgement forms of the type layer:
>
> - $\Gamma \vdash A\; \mathrm{type}$ - $A$ is a well-typed type in context $\Gamma$.
> - $\Gamma \vdash a : A$ - $a$ is a well-typed term of type $A$ in context $\Gamma$.
>
> And the basic judgement forms of the proposition layer:
>
> - $\Gamma \vdash \phi \; \mathrm{prop}$ - $\phi$ is a well-formed proposition in context $\Gamma$
> - $\Gamma \vdash \phi \; \mathrm{true}$ - $\phi$ is a well-formed true proposition in context $\Gamma$
>
> As well as context judgments:
>
> - $\Gamma \; \mathrm{ctx}$ - $\Gamma$ is a well-formed context.
>
> Contexts are defined by the following rules:
>
> $$\frac{}{() \; \mathrm{ctx}} \qquad \frac{\Gamma \; \mathrm{ctx}
>  \quad \Gamma \vdash A \; \mathrm{type}}{(\Gamma, a:A) \; \mathrm{ctx}}
>  \qquad \frac{\Gamma \; \mathrm{ctx} \quad \Gamma \vdash \phi \;
>  \mathrm{prop}}{(\Gamma, \phi \; \mathrm{true}) \; \mathrm{ctx}}$$

Why $\Gamma \; \mathrm{ctx}$, $\Gamma \vdash \phi \; \mathrm{prop}$, $\Gamma \vdash A \; \mathrm{type}$ instead of $\vdash \Gamma : \mathrm{ctx}$, $\Gamma \vdash \phi :\mathrm{prop}$, $\Gamma \vdash A :\mathrm{type}$?

Comment: I think that it is only a notational convention.

Comment: One is the "declaration" stating the category (type) of the term while the other is more similar to "belongs to". But intuitively the two relation ate quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that typed predicate logic (**TPL**) as introduced by [Raymond Turner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Turner_(computer_scientist)) is aimed at being a minimal metatheory. The basic judgements are defined as

1. *T type*$\quad$*T* is a type ,
2. $\phi$ *prop*$\quad\phi$ is a proposition,
3. *t : T*$\qquad$*t* is an object term of type *T*,
4. $\phi\qquad\quad$the proposition $\phi$ is true .

These judgements are expressed in sequents of the form $\Gamma\vdash\Theta$, signifying that judgement $\Theta$ can be made relative to a context $\Gamma$.

Only the judgement *t : T* is an *assignment* (i.e., to a type), the others are declared to *be* so and so.

In some expositions, variations on this notation may be deemed as more suitable to certain purposes. For example, the 4th form of judgement may be written as $\phi$ *true*, though this would actually be needed if $\phi$ could be written with *false*. Likewise, *ctx* is a choice made in the cited contribution.